# How can i return a viewmodel in a layout page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My `_Layout.cshtml` contains

```
 Html.Action("GetCartList", "Shared");
 ShoppingCartViewModel scvm = (ShoppingCartViewModel)ViewData["ShoppingCartViewModel"];
```

My controller

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ShoppingCartViewModel GetCartList()
{
    var results = new ShoppingCartViewModel
    {
               Message = "",
               SomeOtherProperty = "Other"
    };

    ViewData["ShoppingCartViewModel"] = results;
    return  results;
}
```

The question is why the `scvm` is always null?
When the controller "gets hit", the values are loaded successfully to the `ViewData["ShoppingCartViewModel"]`

I wish i could do something like ...

```
ShoppingCartViewModel scvm = Html.Action("GetCartList", "Shared");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your child action, Set the ViewData to your `ParentActionViewContext`.

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public void GetCartList()
{
    var results = new ShoppingCartViewModel
    {
       Message = "",
       SomeOtherProperty = "Other"
    };
    ControllerContext.ParentActionViewContext.ViewData["ShoppingCartViewModel"]=results;  
}
```

And in your Layout,

```
@Html.Action("GetCartList", "Home");
@{

    var scvm = (ShoppingCartViewModel) ViewContext.ViewData["ShoppingCartViewModel"];
    <div> @scvm.SomeOtherProperty </div>
}
```

Comment: Where is the six stars option? Works great!